# torch.utils.data.random_split() is not splitting Dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

I am using `ImageFolder` to load the data from a directory:

```
full_dataset = ImageFolder('some_dir', transform=transform)
```

When I print its length it gives: 32854. Now I want to split the `Dataset` returned by `ImageFolder` into train and test dataset using `torch.utils.data.random_split()`. I tried passing fraction `[0.8, 0.2]`, and length like `[len(full_dataset) - 100, 100]`.

```
train_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(full_dataset, [len(full_dataset) - 100, 100])
```

But when I print both their length using `len(train_dataset.dataset.imgs)` and `len(test_dataset.dataset.imgs)`, they show the same value as `full_dataset`.

Why is my split not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to the original dataset (`full_dataset` in this case) when you do `train_dataset.dataset` (and `test_dataset.dataset` similarly). As a result, the `imgs` attribute on `train_dataset.dataset` (and `test_dataset.dataset`) would give you all the images belonging to the original dataset, not that of each split.

As the `Subset` objects returned by `random_split` have the `__len__` method (`Subset` technically is a subclass of the abstract class `Dataset`), you can get the length of each split/subset using `len` on them directly:

```
len(train_dataset)
len(test_dataset)
```